# WARNING: Form token does not match the session token null

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, double-submit-problem, struts2-interceptors

What is the reason for this warning?

```
WARNING: Form token PR78LAIFZJQRTL66GGAJDT61511L6YHN does not match the session token null
```

**JSP:**

```
<s:form method="post" action="test">
     <s:token></s:token>
     Email:<input name="email" />
</s:form>
```

**Struts.xml:**

```
<action name="test" class="test.RegisterAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
    <interceptor-ref name="token" /> 
    <result name="invalid.token">/error.jsp</result> 
    <result>/user/success.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the interceptor `token` should be first. For example

```
<interceptor-ref name="token" />
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
```

The reason why your session token is `null` might be the session is expired or closed.